# Material becomes undefined when I create a prefab in Unity

Tags: unity, materials

I have a parent GameObject and nested models in it. When I create a prefab, I lose contact with the material in some parts of the model. Why is this happening? And how to avoid this?

Object Hierarchy:

[image]
[image]
The settings themselves:

[image]

prefab on scenes:

[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to reproduce this problem in a new empty project?

Comment: @DMGregory meaning to describe something if there is no one to answer here

Comment: Folks generally won't answer questions they don't understand. Editing your questions to explain can help people understand, and attract useful answers.